# Check dedekind cut for root 2

Tags: real-numbers, dedekind-domain

root 2 corresponds to the Dedekind cut $(A,B)$ where:

$A = \{ x \in \Bbb Q|x\lt 0$ or $x^2\lt 2 \}$

$B = \{ x \in \Bbb Q|x\ge 0$ or $x^2\ge2 \}$

Check that this is a Dedekind cut of $\Bbb Q$ corresponding to a in $\Bbb R$ and $a \ge0, a^2 = 2$
so "$a = \sqrt 2$".

I don't quite understand how $A$ and $B$ have been defined, and what exactly I'm supposed to do, and why. I get that Dedekind cut shows there is a real in between two rationals, but I don't get how to prove it.

Comment: Well, what does "is a Dedekind cut of $\mathbb{Q}$ corresponding to ..." mean in your definitions? The basic point is that (in the language of the real number system that we "don't have yet") $A=(-\infty,\sqrt{2}) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ and $B=(\sqrt{2},\infty) \cap \mathbb{Q}$. Do you see why that is? If not, draw a picture.

Comment: You need to change "or" for "and" in the definition of $B$ in order to make it a Dedekind cut.

Comment: "I don't quite understand how A  and B  have been defined" .  Do you mean you do not understand the set notation?  A is the set of all rational numbers that are **either** negative **or** whose square is less than 2.  B is the set of all positive rational numbers whose square is larger than 2.  (As Jorge said, you need "and" not "or" in your definition of B.)  You are asked to prove this is a "Dedekind Cut".  Okay, what is the **definition** of Dedekind Cut?  Show that these sets satisfy all the conditions of that definition.

Comment: Ian - I'm really not sure. My lecture notes don't explain it very well, and I can't find any explanations online that help me understand how to answer the question.

Comment: user247327 - I get that root 2 lies between A and B and I have to prove that. And the lecture notes said "or" so I guess that's a mistake? I still don't know how to show it other than say that A is before root 2 and B is after root 2 so between them is root 2. I mean what's the point? Why don't we just know that root 2 exists because of pythagoras. What's the point of the Dedekind cut.

Comment: should b e $B = x \in \Bbb Q|x\ge 0 \text{ and } x^2 \ge 2\}$.

Comment: @Seb There are three main ways that people have defined the real number system. One is axiomatic (the reals are the unique complete, ordered, Archimedean field up to isomorphism). Another is from sequences of rational numbers (the reals are the Cauchy completion of the rationals). This approach is nice because it carries the distance directly from the rationals to the reals. The last is from sets of rational numbers (the reals are the collection of all Dedekind cuts of the rationals). This one is nice because it carries the order from the rationals to the reals.

Comment: @Seb Until you've done something like this, you have not formally defined the real numbers.

Comment: @Seb Anyway, to prove that $(A,B)$ is a Dedekind cut, you must show that: 1. every rational is in exactly one of $A$ or $B$; 2. if $x \in A$ and $y<x$ then $y \in A$; 3. if $x \in B$ and $y>x$ then $y \in B$. Start with that.

Comment: @user247327: "B is the set of all positive rational numbers whose square is larger than 2. (As Jorge said, you need "and" not "or" in your definition of B.)" Given that it is a problem statement, it is well possible that "or" is correct, and he is supposed to arrive at the conclusion that it is *not* a Dedekind cut.

Answer (score 2):

The way I learned "Dedekind cut" it applied to only one set, your "$A$", not two but that's not a big deal since, given $A, B$ is automatically defined as its complement.

A set of rational numbers, $A$, is a "Dedekind cut" if and only if

1) $A$ is not empty.  Here, that's obvious- $A$ contains all negative numbers.

2) $A$ is not **all** rational numbers. With your $A$ and $B$, that's the same as saying $B$ is not empty.  Here, this is true because $2$ is not negative and $2^2= 4$ is larger than $2$.  $2$ is not in $A$ (and is in B$$).

3) If $a$ is in $A$ and $b< a$ then $b$ is in $A$. If $a$ is in $A$ either it is a negative number or its square is less than $2$. If $b$ is negative it is in $A$ so we need only look at the case that $0< b< a$.  Then $b^2< a^2< 2$ so $b$ is in $A$.

4) $A$ does not have a largest member- that is usually the hardest part to show.
I would use a "proof by contradiction.  If there exist a largest number, $a$, in $A$, then $a^2< 2$. Let $e= 2- a^2$ which is positive.  Look at $a+re$ for some positive rational number, $r$. $(a+ re)^2= a^2+ 2are+ r^2e^2$.  That is clearly a rational number.  It will be less than $2$ if $2are+ r^2e^2< e$ or $(e^2)r^2+ (2ae)r- 3< 0$.  Show that there exist such a number, $r$.

Comment: So Dedekind cuts in your sense always encode irrationals? (You could perfectly well define Dedekind cuts without your property 4, in which case some Dedekind cuts, e.g. $A=(-\infty,0] \cap \mathbb{Q}$, encode rationals.)

Comment: @Ian: You misunderstood. To encode 0, as in your example, use the rational numbers _less_than_ 0. This set satisfies property 4. The point is that rational numbers can be defined your way, but irrational numbers cannot. The method user247327 described works for both rationals and irrationals.

Comment: @user3697176 Both ways work, but after seeing your point I agree that the alternative (where a rational cut misses one rational number) is cleaner. But irrational numbers can indeed be defined the other way, basically because $(-\infty,r] \cap \mathbb{Q} = (-\infty,r) \cap \mathbb{Q}$ if $r \not \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Ian. You cannot define $\sqrt{2}$ in this fashion; your definition is _circular_! (Of course you could define the cut for $\sqrt{2}$ using $A = \{\ldots\le2\}$, but then you need to replace 4) by the requirement that the _complement_ of A has no lower bound, which is distinctly awkward.)

Comment: @user3697176 As written it's circular, but the point is to encode the interval in some inequality that can be formulated only in the language of rationals (which in this case is easy). But you're right, there is some awkwardness then.

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts (seven out of 8 answers you posted yesterday!) need heavy editing.